# insert into a jsonb column selecting from different table in psql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-insert

insert into a jsonb column selecting from different table in psql. i want the jsonb insert like

```
{"name": "myname" ,"email": "test@gmail.com"}
```

I want to do some thing like this "name": "myname" constant value and email is select from another table

```
insert into test1 (column1) select {"name": "myname" ,"email": email}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use row_to_json to convert the selected rows into json. Then cast to jsob if necessary.

```
insert into test1 (column1)
select row_to_json(x)::jsonb from (select 'myname' as name, email from another_table) x;
```